# Formal definition of equation and unknowns

Tags: logic

I was just wondering about the formal definition of equation, I mean in terms of logic and the theory of sets. Suppose for example I wanted to define an equation on $\mathbb{R}$, of course it might be anything instead. I know every number is a set, and also I know that equality of sets has been defined previously. So I often hear people say something like "A linear equation is an object of the form $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+ \cdots + a_{n}x_{n}=b$".  But how do you justify the part of "$x_{i}$ is an unknown". Because in that case I would also say that $3(2)+4(5)=0 $ is an equation.

Comment: By quantifying (universal) over things in $\mathbb R$ (one quantifier for each $x_i$) maybe?

Comment: The possibilities depend a bit on how your language is constructed, and the notion of an equation may be implicit in the way that "=" is defined in that language. You may also want to consider what sense you might want to make of "equations" like $x^2=2$ and $x^2=-1$ - are they allowed to be equations or not? Some languages have explicit terms which can function as "unknowns" specifically because they are constructed to allow expressions such as you give for a linear equation.

Comment: I think Berci's and DoubleTrouble's answers are good ones in terms of defining "equation" just like mathematicians do by using the rules of logic (that was in fact what I was trying to mean in my question). But Makhlom's answer is more of philosophical treatment and his point is on the formal definition of "equation in general", as a component of the rules of logic, very nice conception. So I chose Makholm's answer as the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't find a formal definition of "equation" and "unknown", because they are partially *informal* concepts. The formula on the paper is what it is: two expressions, usually containing variables, joined by an equals sign. But there's no fixed rule that will tell you, from looking at the formula, which of the variables (if any) are unknowns.

Being an "unknown" is *not* a property of a variable or a formula. It expresses something about what you, the human mathematician looking at it *intend to do with the equation*. The roles of unknowns and constants can change simply by virtue of you *changing your mind*.

For example, if we're looking at the formula
$$ x^2+y^2=1 $$
we can choose to "solve for $x$", that is, treat the variable $x$ as an unknown and everything else as constants -- and we'd end up with $x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ -- or we could have made a different choice end with $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ instead. Neither approach to the formula is objectively right or wrong. One of them may lead us closer to whatever our eventual goal is, but the formula itself doesn't know what that eventual goal is.

In particular when we say "treat $x$ as an unknown", there is *no* implied "... even though it really isn't". *Nothing* is an unknown in and of itself; variables are unknowns when and if we choose to treat them like one.

Also note that the *formal* rules of what one is allowed to do to a formula doesn't distinguish between knowns and unknowns. We can *always* replace $(p+q)^2$ with $p^2+q^2+pq+qp$, no matter whether $p$ and $q$ are knowns, unknowns, or some complex things built from several of each.

Comment: Are you stating that *equation* is a primitive concept?

Comment: No, I'm stating that it is an _informal_ one, describing _what we do_ with formulas rather than _what they are_. (Specific concept such as a "quadratic equation" are a somewhat different matter).

Comment: I don't really get what an informal concept it. If it isn't a mathematical concept, then it must be a primitive concept.

Comment: @GitGud: Your usage of at least one of those terms must be very strange. Do you think "papal conclave" is a "primitive concept"? It certainly isn't a mathematical one.

Comment: Primitive concepts depend on which theory you're working on. If you can't (or choose not to) define something, then, after transmitting an idea of what you want that thing to mean, it becomes a primitive concept with respect to that theory.

Comment: @GitGud: The point is that "unknown" and "equation" _are not even part of the theory_. They are informal ideas in our mind that we use to describe our plans for _what to do_ with the theory, but the theory doesn't know about them, neither as primitive or defined concepts.

Comment: I'm way in over my head here, but I'm not convinced at all. Also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) it says: *Expressions and their evaluation were $\textbf{formalised}$ by Alonzo Church and Stephen Kleene in the 1930s in their lambda calculus.*

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not a logician, so probably it is nonsense what I'm going to say. When we define the rules of logic, then it should be symbols, some of them are variable and some others are constants. So I was trying to understand Git Gud's point in the sense that "unknown" is implicit in such "variable symbols" so basically the concept is a primitive one.

Comment: @GitGud: I'm speaking about "equation" and "unknown" here, not "expression".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, but if *expression* can be defined, then equation can't be that far, or am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: Yes, there is a formal distinction in logic between "variable symbols" and "constant symbols". However, according to that distinction, "constant symbols" are things like "0" and "7", whereas things like "$a$" and "$x$" are both variable symbols. In $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the constant symbols are 0 and 2, whereas $a,b,c,x$ are all variables. When we solve the quadratic equation we _treat_ $x$ differently from $a$, $b$, and $c$, but the difference is in our _choices_, not in any _formal_ distinction between those four variables. (...)

Comment: (...) From a formal logic standpoint we can express the difference as "we treat $a, b, c$ _as if_ they were constant symbols", which works because everything the rules of logic allows us to do to a constant symbol they also allow us to do to a variable. But this difference is still one of _intent_, not of something that exists at the raw level of formal proofs.

Answer (score 5):

I would pick a set $x$ which is different from all the numbers we want to use, and regard it *as an unknown* in the formalism.
Then, for an $n\in\Bbb N$, $\ x_n:=\langle x,n\rangle$ (ordered pair).

Then, define *terms* as finite sequences, using these variables, perhaps the numbers, and the operation symbols (for these, a new, so far unused sets can be used).

Then, an *equation* would be an ordered pair $\langle\tau,\sigma\rangle$ of terms. Its meaning is defined then straightforwardly.

Comment: This is one of the most set-theoretic, formalistic definitions I have ever seen. +1.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that an equation is a logical predicate. That is, an open dictum whos truth value is determined by some input e.g.

$$P(x) \ : \ x + 2 = 4$$

where $x$ belongs to some domain. To solve an equation is to find the (possibly infinitely long) truth table for this predicate.

Comment: Well, yes, except that some predicates are not equations. For example $Q(x) \equiv x>3$ is not an equation. And most times when we solve equations that are no "truth tables" involved. What a solution means here is just a _simpler description_ of the solution set, where the meaning of "simpler" depends on context and intentions.

Comment: I didn't say that all predicates are equations. Just that an equation can be considered to be a predicate. OP asked for the formal logical explaination of an equation and what it means to solve it. I don't believe he asked for simplification.

Comment: However talking about "find the infintely long truth table" _is_ a simplification of what we do when we solve equations. What we _actually_ do is to find a description of the solution set that is simpler and/or easier to work with than the description provided by the equation itself.

Comment: But what are the solution set but merely the values that render the predicate true?

Comment: x @Double: Exactly. From a formal logical point of view, simply writing, say, $$\{ x\mid 7x^5+x^4-22x^3+8872x-1=0\}$$ is a perfectly good construction of that solution set. So what we're doing when _solving_ the equation is not "finding the solution set" or "finding the truth table", because logically we _already have it_ by a few strokes of the pen. The task is to find a _description_ of the solution set that is easier to work with (for the purposes at hand) than the one above. And that is not a question of formal logic, but of extra-logical intent.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't understad you point YET. Please tell me, what is wrong in doing this definition of linear equation: Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. A linear equation in $n$ unknowns is an object of the form $a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\cdots +a_{n}x_{n}=a$. The objects $x_{i}$ & $a_{i}$, $1\leq i \leq n$ are variables and constants, respectively.$a$ is a constant too. Variables are called unknowns and we will say that $(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n})$ is a solution of the equation if and only if $a_{1}\alpha_{1}+a_{2}\alpha_{2}+\cdots +a_{n}\alpha_{n}=a$. I've tried to follow DTrouble's idea.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: (This seems to belong more in the thread under my answer, or am I misunderstanding you?) There's nothing wrong with defining "linear equation" in this way and then define what you want "unknowns" to mean in the context of that definition. What I'm saying is that there's no formal definition of "unknown" _in general_ (that is, _without_ the restriction to unknowns of a _linear_ equation in canonical form) which matches the way mathematicians use the word in practice.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I posted my answer here because I tried to follow DoubleTroble's idea about defining an equeation as some specific predicate, in this case $P(x):a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+\cdots +a_{n}x_{n}=a$. But you're right, it makes sense only in some specific scope (I think it will work for numbers in general, I'm not sure about any other object).